# contract testing returning total supply 0

Tags: solidity

So I am new to solidity and following this tutorial - [Code Your Own Cryptocurrency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdKv5uwEk5A&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n).

And I am running some tests on truffle and I have two failed tests not sure why-

1. The first is to make sure that the contract allocates the tokens to the correct admin address.
2. To make a transfer function.

Here is my solidity -

```
    contract WhiteCrypto{

    //Token id

    string  public name = "White Crypto";
    string  public symbol = "WHC";
    string public standard = "White Crypto v1.0";

    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(

    address indexed _from,
    address indexed _to,
    uint256 _value
   );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    

        function WhiteCryptoFunction (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
            balanceOf[msg.sender]= _initialSupply;
            totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    //transfer functions
    function transfer(address _to,uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
       require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >=_value);

       balanceOf[msg.sender] -=_value;
       balanceOf[_to] += _value;

       emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

       return true;

        }
```

and JS code:

```
var WhiteCrypto = artifacts.require("./WhiteCrypto.sol");
```

contract('WhiteCrypto', function(accounts){
var tokenInstance;

```
it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function(){
    return WhiteCrypto.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return tokenInstance.name();
    }).then(function(name){
    assert.equal(name, 'White Crypto', 'has the correct name');
    return tokenInstance.symbol();
    }).then(function(symbol){
        assert.equal(symbol, 'WHC' , 'has the correct symbol');
        return tokenInstance.standard();
    }).then(function(standard){
        assert.equal(standard, 'White Crypto v1.0', 'has the correct standard');
    });

})

it('allocates the total supply upon deployment', function() {

    return WhiteCrypto.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return tokenInstance.totalSupply();

    }).then(function(totalSupply) {
        assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(),360000000, 'sets the total supply to 360,000,000');
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(adminBalance){
        assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(),360000000, 'it allocates the initial supply to the admin balance')
    });

});

it('transfers token ownership', function(){
    return WhiteCrypto.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;

        //will test the statement ( not having enough tokens) by transferring something larger than the senders balance
        return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1],99999999999999999999999999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >=0, 'error message must contain revert');
        return tokenInstance.transfer.call(account[1],250000, {from: accounts[0]});
    }). then(function(success){
        assert.equal(success,true,'it returns true');
        return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 250000,{from: accounts[0]});
    }).then(function(receipt){
        assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'should be the "Transfer" event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._from, accounts[0], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred from');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._to, accounts[1], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred to');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value, 250000, 'logs the transfer amount');
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(),250000,'adds the amount to the receiving account');
        return tokenInstance.blaanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 750000, 'dedcuts the amount from the sending account');
    });
});
```

});

and the errors -

```
Contract: WhiteCrypto
√ initializes the contract with the correct values (388ms)
1) allocates the total supply upon deployment
> No events were emitted
2) transfers token ownership
> No events were emitted
```

1 passing (763ms)
2 failing

1. Contract: WhiteCrypto
   allocates the total supply upon deployment:

   it allocates the initial supply to the admin balance

   - expected - actual

   -0
   +360000000

   at C:\Users\Foxy098\WhiteCrypto\test\WhiteCrypto.js:32:20
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
2. Contract: WhiteCrypto
   transfers token ownership:
   AssertionError: error message must contain revert
   at C:\Users\Foxy098\WhiteCrypto\test\WhiteCrypto.js:44:13
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use code below instead of "WhiteCryptoFunction" function

```
constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
   balanceOf[msg.sender]= _initialSupply;
   totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```

Comment: Wont compile -error: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.

Comment: You don't need to use public for contructor function

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: 1) Contract: WhiteCrypto
       allocates the total supply upon deployment:

      sets the total supply to 360,000,000
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +360000000

      at C:\Users\Foxy098\WhiteCrypto\test\WhiteCrypto.js:29:20
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: I am not sure about this error but, do you set constructor argument? like WhiteCrypto.deployed(360000000 * 10 ** 18)

Comment: When using Constructor that you provided I get this error after trying to compile- project:/contracts/WhiteCrypto.sol:21:4: SyntaxError: No visibility specified. Did you intend to add "public"?
   constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).  

But when I add public to the code I get this - Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.

Comment: what is your pragma